# when i opening the website on the dashboard it's fine but when logging in as admin there is an http error 500, what could be the problem?

Tags: php, json, laravel, .htaccess, codeigniter

when i opening the website on the dashboard it's fine but when logging in as admin there is an http error 500, what could be the problem?

and how i bring up the debug, i use this but can't appear in my website :

; Debug Settings ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[debug]

; Display execution stats in the footer

show_stats =  On

; Display a stack trace when a fatal error occurs.
; Note that this may expose private information and should be disabled
; for any production system.

show_stacktrace = On

; Display an error message when something goes wrong.

display_errors = On

; Display deprecation warnings

deprecation_warnings = On

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbXpJ.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For showing error go to `.env` file
and set the `app_debug=true`.

Comment: im new in my office, in this codding dont have .env